# How give users ability to change their blog pages theme?

Tags: theming, nodes

I am using Drupal7 and I am designing a blog engine site that any user can create a blog for him/herself and he/she can change the theme of his/her blog page. Is there any module to integrate with the core blog module and provides this ability for my site?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Switchtheme](http://drupal.org/project/switchtheme) module.

> Adds a block to allow users to switch between enabled themes.

Read the readme.txt of the module for the instructions.

If you wish to have different themes according to roles, take a look at the [Role Theme Switcher](http://drupal.org/project/role_theme_switcher) module.

> Useful Drupal module to assign separate themes for different roles (including anonymous) in your system.

Comment: This is not really what I want. This module just change the theme of the whole site for that user, and when I go to that user blog page from admin session the theme of the user blog is the site default theme. I want a user can change just his/her blog page theme and all other users view his/her blog page in theme that his/her defined. All users have example.com/blogs/username blog page.